# How do I remove the title from the_content

Tags: the-content

I have this code that I use to get the posts that are in a certain category. The problem is the function `the_content()` returns the title of the page at the top of the rest of the content.

Is there a way to filter the title out? I am not sure how to use filters and I am not sure that is what I am supposed to be using for this?

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
  'posts_per_page' => 30,                
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array( 'services' ),
  ),)
);
$additional_loop = new WP_Query($args); 
while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : $additional_loop->the_post();
?>  
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post_article">
  <div class="col-xs-12  no_pad">
      <h3><?php echo the_title();?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Just to be clear, the code above will out put something like:

```
<article id="post-111" class="post_article">
  <div class="col-xs-12  no_pad">
      <h3>This is my title</h3>
      This is my title<br />
      This is the rest of the content for the post. bla bla bla
  </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I have not found an answer to my question. I did find a workaround. Here is my work around. I ended up using the_excerpt instead. Then added code to the function.php file so that I could control the length of the excerpt.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'suppress_filters' => true,
  'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
  'posts_per_page' => 30,                
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'field'    => 'slug',
    'terms'    => array( 'services' ),
  ),)
);
$additional_loop = new WP_Query($args); 
while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : $additional_loop->the_post();
?>  
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="post_article">
  <div class="col-xs-12  no_pad">
      <h3><?php echo the_title();?></h3>
    <?php the_exerpt(); ?>
    <p><a class="btn btn-default read-more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">Read More</a></p>

  </div>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

This is the function that I put in the function.php

```
function wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 300;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpdocs_custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

I would still love to know how to get the title out of the_content(). Meaning I do not want the title to be printed out when I use the function the_content()

Comment: This is not the normal behaviour of `the_content()`. Does the content actually include the title? If not you likely have a filter somewhere that is adding it to begin with.

Comment: hummmm. This is not the first time I have run into this. The other time I was using a different theme and NO the title is not actually in the content. 
Maybe I should try searching the code for 
add_filter( 'the_content'

Comment: If you remove the `the_title()` part, leaving just the `the_content()` part, does the same issue persists? Or try vice-versa - remove the latter part and keep the former.

Comment: Yes. it does.

I also tried searching the entire site for  add_filter. With only looking at the code that comes directly after add_filter, I do not see any filter that could have produced this error

Comment: I have edited your post - the sample HTML output was not properly formatted. So if you look at that output, the duplicate title is part of the post content *or maybe the excerpt*, so you could try looking for `the_excerpt`, and/or try deactivating all plugins and see if that helps. There could also be some JS which added the extra title there, so try checking for suspicious scripts.

Comment: Were you able to resolve? If yes please post solution as a separate answer, it could help others in the future. P.S.: I see you have `$additional_loop` - perhaps it's interfering with the main loop.

Comment: $additional_loop is the only loop on the page. Does it matter what I call it?

No, I have not solved this issue. I did come up with a solution. Only I would really like to get an answer to this. I will post the code that I found worked

Comment: @PeggyMe, "I also tried searching the entire site for add_filter" - have you actually tried searching for `add_action( 'the_content'` (or other variations like `add_action("the_content"`)? (It shouldn't be `add_action` because `the_content` is a *filter*, but just in case) Are you absolutely sure this wasn't a plugin issue? (Did you try deactivating all plugins?)

Answer (score -2):

you need to remove the `echo` from the `the_title()`.

Change this:

```
<h3><?php the_title();?></h3>
```

Source : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/

Comment: You are right, the echo should not be there. Only that is not the problem. The problem is that the title comes in along with the content. See, the title is on the page two times.